# How to get the table details based on post request django

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
**views.py**

[if request.method == "POST":
    from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
    print(from_date)
    to_date = request.POST.get("to_date")
    print(to_date)
    get_date_from_dates = Scrapper.objects.all().filter(created_at=from_date, updated_at=to_date)
    print(len(get_date_from_dates))
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(get_date_from_dates, 5)
    global users
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

else:
    user_list =  Scrapper.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 5)
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, "home.html", { 'users': users })

return render(request, "home.html", {'users': users})][1]



**home.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
<style>
  h2 {text-align: center;}
</style>
<h1>Facilgo Completed Jobs</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="from_date">From Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date">
   <label for="to_date">To Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="to_date" name="to_date">
  <input type="submit"><br>
</form>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Summary Details</h2>
  <table id="bootstrapdatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>user_registration_source_id</th>
      <th>user_type</th>
      <th>user_id</th>
      <th>source</th>
      <th>source_url</th>
      <th>created at</th>
      <th>updated at</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for stud in users %}
    {% csrf_token %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{stud.user_registration_source_id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.user_type}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.user_id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.source}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.source_url}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.updated_at}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
    {% if users.has_other_pages %}
    <ul class="pagination">
   {% if users.has_previous %}
     <li><a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">«</a></li>
   {% else %}
     <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
   {% endif %}
   {% if user.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:'-5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
   {% endif %}
   {% for i in users.paginator.page_range %}
     {% if users.number == i %}
    <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
    {% elif i > users.number|add:'-5' and i < users.number|add:'5' %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% if users.has_next %}
     <li><a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">»</a></li>
   {% else %}
     <li class="disabled"><span>»</span></li>
   {% endif %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSXVa.png)

When I post my from date and to date it would check the "created at" and "updated at" field in table and able to view only the datas of particular date. I have written the post request and get the from date and to date from the form. Is there any solution after posting data only get the values of particular dates in table. But at the opening the webpage it should show all datas in table

Output:

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqRPO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think its better approach to use a certain time period if not chosen by the user. for example one month range.

```
from datetime import date as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

if request.method == "POST":
    if "from_date" and "to_date" in request.POST:
        from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
        to_date = request.POST.get("to_date")
    else:
        from_date = dt.today()
        to_date = today + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

and then filter with this dates.

Comment: get_date_from_dates = Scrapper.objects.all().filter(created_at=from_date, updated_at=to_date)
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(get_date_from_dates, 5)

Comment: This is what I have done but when I click page 2 it showing all details. If there is 10 details show only ten page 1,2 ... 5,5 ..

Comment: you're having trouble with pagination or filtering with date?

Comment: Pagination. After filtering the data my first page get 5 records of particular dates. But when I click page 2 it is showing different datas of different dates. I need to get exact datas numbers for particular dates

Comment: if request.method == "POST":
        from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
     
        to_date = request.POST.get("to_date")
       
        get_date_from_dates = Scrapper.objects.all().filter(created_at=from_date, updated_at=to_date)
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(get_date_from_dates, 5)
        global users
        try:
            users = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            users = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

Comment: please update the question with what you tried and what results are you getting and what is expected.

Comment: In output Image its  page which is not showing the exact details of the dates selected